# loop through vector in R to delete objects containing pattern above certain limit

Tags: r, regex, loops, vector

Trying to figure out how to loop through a vector and eliminate components containing a particular pattern above a predetermined limit. For example, in the following vector, I might want to keep just the first two instances of both the "a_a_" and  "b_b_" components.

```
x <- c("a_a_a", "a_a_b", "a_a_c", "a_a_d", "b_b_a", "b_b_b", "b_b_c", "b_b_d")
```

The resulting vector, after the loop deleting extraneous components, would be like this:

```
x = "a_a_a", "a_a_b", "b_b_a", "b_b_b"
```

The tricky part is that the code must first detect what is contained in the pattern, then loop through the (extremely long) vector to find all matching patterns, and establish a means of counting instances so that once it hits that given level, it then eliminates all matching components thereafter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to identify which elements have the patterns and keep only the first two.

```
patterns = c("a_a", "b_b")
keep = NULL
for(p in patterns) { keep = c(keep, grep(p,x)[1:2]) }
x = x[keep]
x
[1] "a_a_a" "a_a_b" "b_b_a" "b_b_b"
```

Comment: Thanks! That is almost all. The one additional thing I need to do is loop through the vector and actually detect the pattern that I need to be using, so  like this:
patterns = grep('*_*_', x, value = TRUE)
But I think I can figure that out from here. Going to try at any rate. Thank you again.

Comment: Are the patterns always of the form  letter-underscore-letter ?

Comment: yes, essentially, letter(s) underscore letter(s) underscore.

Comment: figured out the gsub regex I needed:

`gsub("[A-Za-z]*'*-*[A-Za-z]*$", "", x)`